# contractLogicError on Web3 but working on Remix

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, error

I have this contract code, which works fine on remix, but I cannot run with web3 in python, getting a contractLogicError.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface IERC20 {

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 numTokens) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address receiver, uint256 numTokens) external returns (bool);

    function changeLeader(address newLeader) external returns(bool);
}

contract ownableERC20 is IERC20 {

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    uint8 private _decimals;
    uint256  private _totalSupply;

    address public owner;
    address public leader;

    mapping(address => uint256) _balances;
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) _allowances;


    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_,uint256 totalSupply_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _totalSupply = totalSupply_;
        _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender] + totalSupply_;

        emit Transfer(address(0),msg.sender,_totalSupply);
    }

    function _transfer(address sender, address receiver, uint256 numTokens) internal {
        require(receiver != address(0),"ERC20: transfer from zero transfer");
        require(sender != address(0),"ERC20: transfer from zero transfer");
        require(numTokens <= _balances[sender]);
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender]-numTokens;
        _balances[receiver] = _balances[receiver]+numTokens;

        emit Transfer(sender, receiver, numTokens);
    }

    function _approve(address owning, address spender, uint256 numTokens) internal {
        require(spender != address(0),"ERC20: transfer from zero transfer");
        require(owning != address(0),"ERC20: transfer from zero transfer");
        _allowances[owning][spender] = numTokens;

        emit Approval(owning, spender, numTokens);
    }

    // function name() public view returns (string memory) {
    //     return _name;
    // }

    // function symbol() public view  returns (string memory){
    //     return _symbol;
    // }

    // function decimals() public view returns(uint8) {
    //     return _decimals;
    // }
    // function decimals() public override pure returns (uint8) {
    //     return true;
    // }

    function _mint(address account, uint256 numTokens) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");
        _totalSupply += numTokens;
        _balances[account] += numTokens;

        emit Transfer(address(0), account, numTokens);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 numTokens) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");
        uint256 accountBalance = _balances[account];
        require(accountBalance >= numTokens, "ERC20: burn numTokens exceeds balance");
        _balances[account] = accountBalance - numTokens;
        _totalSupply -= numTokens;

        emit Transfer(account, address(0), numTokens);
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(msg.sender,receiver,numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(msg.sender, spender, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owning, address spender) public override view returns(uint256) {
        return _allowances[owning][spender];
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns(bool) {
        _transfer(sender, receiver, numTokens);
        _approve(sender, msg.sender, _allowances[sender][msg.sender] - numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function changeLeader(address newLeader) public override returns(bool){
        require(leader == msg.sender);
        leader = newLeader;
        return true;
    }

}

contract emissionsTradeToken is ownableERC20{

    mapping(address => uint256) GHGEmitted;
    mapping(address=>address) approvedIot;
    mapping(address=>bool) approvedAgent;

    event Buy(address indexed to, uint indexed GHGEmitted, uint indexed amount);
    event Emission(address indexed to, uint indexed GHGEmitted, uint indexed amount);
    event Compensate(address indexed to, uint indexed GHGEmitted, uint indexed amount);

    constructor() ownableERC20("emissionsTradeToken", "ETT", 100000000000000000000){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyLeader(){
        require(msg.sender == leader);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyIOT(address agent){
        require(msg.sender == approvedIot[agent]);
        _;
    }

    // function mint(uint amount) public onlyOwner{
    //     _mint(address(this), amount);
    // }

    function addEmissions(address agent,uint emission) public onlyIOT(agent){
        GHGEmitted[agent] += emission;
        emit Emission(agent,emission,emission);
    }

    function getEmissions(address agent) public view returns(uint){
        return GHGEmitted[agent];
    }

    function getIOTCounter(address agent) public view returns(address){
        return approvedIot[agent];
    }

    function compensate(uint amount) public{
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender)>= amount, "buy ETT to compensate for GHG emissions!");
        //_burn(msg.sender,amount);
        transfer(owner,amount);
        GHGEmitted[msg.sender] -=amount;
        emit Compensate(msg.sender,amount, amount);
    }

    function approveAgent(address agent) onlyLeader public{
        // eventually, requires no again adding if already added
        require(approvedAgent[agent]==false, "agent already added");
        approvedAgent[agent]=true;
    }

    function approveIOTCounter(address spender) public{
        require(approvedAgent[msg.sender]==true, "agent must be added ny contract owner - community manager");
        bool isApproved = approve(spender,getEmissions(msg.sender));
        if(isApproved)
            approvedIot[msg.sender]=spender;
    }

}

contract tradeContract {

    address public owner;

    IERC20 public token;

    event Bought(uint256 numTokens);
    event Sold(uint256 numTokens);

    constructor() {
        token = new emissionsTradeToken();
        owner = msg.sender;
        token.changeLeader(msg.sender);
    }

    function buy() payable public {
        uint256 amountTobuy = msg.value;
        uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(amountTobuy > 0, "You need to send some ether");
        require(amountTobuy <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
        token.transfer(msg.sender, amountTobuy);

        emit Bought(amountTobuy);
    }

    // function getbal(address wallet) public view returns (uint){return token.balanceOf(wallet);}
    // function isOwner() public view returns (address){return owner;}

    function sell(uint256 numTokens) public {
        require(numTokens > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
        uint256 allow = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allow >= numTokens, "Check the token allowance");
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), numTokens);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(numTokens);

        emit Sold(numTokens);
    }
}
```

aparently the end is at token.changeLeader(msg.sender) because when I take it out the code works.

In python, the piece of code where I call the contract is just:

```
def deploy_contract(w3, acct, contract_interface):
    tx_hash = w3.eth.contract(
        abi=contract_interface['abi'],
        bytecode=contract_interface['bin']).constructor().transact({
        # 'type': '0x2',
        'from': acct.address,
        'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct.address),
        'maxFeePerGas': 50000000000,  # required for dynamic fee transactions
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 1000000000,  # required for dynamic fee transactions
         })
    print(tx_hash.hex())
    contractReceipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said the problem is the function `changeLeader`

```
function changeLeader(address newLeader) public override returns(bool){
    require(leader == msg.sender);
    leader = newLeader;
    return true;
}
```

It requires `leader` to be initialized but it is never initialized so it will be the zero address and when calling `changeLeader` it will revert because it will be different from `msg.sender`.

Comment: yes I actually also solved it just before going to bed, but thanks